# No sound after upgrading

Tags: 13.04

It was working perfectly before and after it restarted it's gone. I need sound desperately  since I am recording.
I tried typing alsamixer into the terminal as someone suggested but nothing came up.

Answer (score 0):

you can give a try to:

```
sudo alsaconf
```

which should be in the alsa-utils package along with alsamixer.